# dehabilitar el bloqueo de ventanas emergentes

Tags: javascript

Quiero que el usuario introduzca un valor por medio de un Alert. 
Si bloquea las ventanas emergentes para el script. 
Hay alguna manera de saltar la linea de introducción de datos si el usuario bloquea las ventanas emergentes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra opción, si la pregunta que le haces al usuario es muy simple, en vez de usar una ventana emergente utilizar un [`prompt`](http://devdocs.io/dom/window/prompt) que es para eso.

Answer (score 4):

Podrias detectar si la ventana no puede abrirse

[Test For Popup Blocker Using JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/popup-block-javascript)

evaluando la variable que tendra la instancia de la ventana.

```
 var popUp = window.open('url', '', 'options');
 if (popUp == null || typeof(popUp)=='undefined') {     
     alert('Se bloqueo el popup'); 
  }
```

En realidad no saltas la línea sino que la ejecutas y evaluas si pudo abrirse la ventana o no.

Una recomendacion, poque no usas popup implementado en jquery

[Jquery UI Dialogo](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

con esto ya no tendras problema de bloqueo de las ventana porque ejecuta dentro de la misma.

Comment: Lo probaré. Ahora estoy aprendiendo JS, más adelante tendré que empezar con Jquery

Comment: Interesante @Leandrotuttini , esto sirve para la mayoría de los navegadores, cual es tu experiencia?